# Sentence order: Where to put もう

Tags: syntax, word-usage, jlpt

This is the sentential question I found in Sou Matome :

> 母親「さあ、もうねなさい。」
>
> こども「この_ _ * _ ちょっとまって。」
>
> A. おわる、B. もう、C. ゲームが、D.まで

I answered:

> ゲームが**もう**終わるまでちょっとまって。

but the answer is :

> ゲームが終わるまで**もう**ちょっとまって

Why is もう placed before ちょっと and not おわる? I thought since もう is an adverb then the safest place is before a verb? Is there a rule where もう should be placed?

Comment: `あさ、もうねなさい。` <-  You meant to type さあ, not あさ, no?

Comment: Yes! Wow how did you notice that? Is it because あさ doesn't make sense on the sentence?

Comment: It would make sense only if the kid's name were あさ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the typo: 終わ**り**まで -> 終わ**る**まで.

Next you should really consider the meaning of the sentence you are trying to construct as well as the grammar. What do you think もう would mean if the sentence was ゲームがもう終わるまで...? Until the game finishes more?/now?/soon?/already? None of these make much sense to me.

There is another verb in the sentence, and there is another adverb, and it's important to remember that adverbs can modify other adverbs as well as nouns. We have まって meaning 'wait'. This is modified by the adverb ちょっと to give ちょっとまって "Wait a bit". We can then modify all of this with the adverb もう to give もうちょっとまって "wait a bit more/longer".

Altogether we have:

> このゲームが終わるまでもうちょっとまって。
>   Wait a bit longer until this game finishes.